# useEffect and undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm trying to kick off undefined, but I don't understand, what I'm doing wrong. I need to initialize persons without undefined[image]

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SearchBar } from "./SearchBar";
import { getPersons } from "../../apies/api";
import { ListOfPersons } from "./listOfPersons";
const Home = () => {
    const [valueOfInput, valueOfInputChange] = useState("")
    const [persons, setPersons] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        getPersons().then(response => setPersons(response))
    }, [setPersons]); 
    console.log(persons)

    return <div>
       <h1>Поиск персонажей</h1>
       <SearchBar personGetRequest={valueOfInputChange}/> 
       <ListOfPersons personsList={persons}/>
    </div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the persons with empty array then it will not show undefined. Like the below code

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to:

1. Call the function getPersons only on mount of
   the component with an empty array in the dependencies array
2. Inizialize the persons state with an empty array
3. Be careful about the type of the response of your api (an object with `count`,`next`,`previous`,`result` fields), in order to call the function setPersons with the `result`
4. Take care of errors when call the getPersons api with a catch statement which will set an empty array, for example.
5. You may would read persons only when persons change instead of every render, so you could put your console.log inside an useEffect with persons array inside the dependencies array.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SearchBar } from "./SearchBar";
import { getPersons } from "../../apies/api";
import { ListOfPersons } from "./listOfPersons";
const Home = () => {
    const [valueOfInput, valueOfInputChange] = useState("")
    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getPersons()
         .then(response => setPersons(response.data.results))
         .catch(e => setPersons([])
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>console.log(persons),[persons])

    return <div>
       <h1>Поиск персонажей</h1>
       <SearchBar personGetRequest={valueOfInputChange}/> 
       <ListOfPersons personsList={persons}/>
    </div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use this for fetching data

```
useEffect(() => {
   getPersons().then(response => setPersons(response.data.data))
}, [setPersons]); 

console.log(persons)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What makes you think that `response` has a `data` property and how does this fix OPs `undefined` issue? By the screenshot provided, `response` does not seem to have a `data` property so it looks like this code will throw an error